# Config virtual hosts on Apache 2.4 via webmin on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: apache, ssl, ssl-certificate, webmin, virtualmin

I'm having some troubles trying to config my apache server to host multiple domains. In this moment i have only one, but i want to keep it prepared to host more. I don't know how to make the server listens ports 80 and 443 with SSL enabled. i have this config on my .conf file of the virtual host:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /var/www/mygamingmoments
ServerName mygamingmoments.es
<Directory "/var/www/html/mygamingmoments">
allow from all
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
Require all granted
AllowOverride All
RewriteEngine On
RewriteOptions Inherit
</Directory>
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/mygamingmoments.es/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/mygamingmoments.es/privkey.pem
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

The fact is that now i can enter my site with https but if i didn't write this, the virtual host seems not working.

Greetings.

Comment: Hi Victor, welcome to SO! Please edit your question and include the actual code, instead of a screenshot. This allows SO users to paste your code in their tool, and give you better feedback and updated code. Good luck and welcome!

Answer (score 0):

There is many approaches for make Apache set up, so I will show something that you probably will want to do.

If what you need to do is to redirect all traffic for port 80 for 443, to prevent access be http or https depending on what port you put after your domain you can do something like this or adapt to your real intent.

So in your Virtual Host for port 80 you need something like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

ServerName your-domain.something
ServerAlias www.your-domain.somenthing
DocumentRoot /path/to/source

    <Directory /path/to/source>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =your-domain.something [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.your-domain.somenthing
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

Here each request to your site or app, whatever, with *www* or without *www* will redirect to another virtual host with https protocol, so you need to create it.

Virtual host for port 443.

```
<VirtualHost *:443>

ServerName your-domain.something
ServerAlias www.your-domain.somenthing
DocumentRoot /path/to/source

    <Directory /path/to/source>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

Include /path/to/options-ssl-apache.conf
SSLCertificateFile /path/to/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /path/to/privkey.pem

</VirtualHost>
```

You can do this on the same file or in another file for better organization (my-site.conf for example), but if you choose to do in another you must add this 'site' to sites enabled of apache environment with *a2ensite*:

```
# a2ensite path-to-your-config-file

# systemctl reload apache2
```

With this sample, you should to know that if you want have **various sites** in you environment, **you will need of each site has it own Virtual Host**. In this approach one Virtual Host for port 80 and one correspondent to port 433. And the key for that is make the requests matches with ServerName ou ServerAlias option at each Virtual Host.

I Hope it helps.

Comment: Seems that it works! I did in the same .conf file. But now the htaccess rewrite rules don't work. Don't know why because i didn't change the rules in the .conf file.

Comment: AllowOverride None in my sample is make your .htacess fully disabled. httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/pt-br/howto/htaccess.html

Comment: Hmmm dont know why but, i have AllowOverride All on both virtual host config files and htaccess still not working.

Comment: Solved i think! I had to put AllowOverride All on de apache2.conf default file in Directory var/www/. Seems everything is working now! Thanks!

Comment: If your Apache version is later than 2.3.9, the default is AllowOverride None. Then you will need explicit use directive AllowOverride All as the simple way to allow .htaccess directives override the default configuration. An important directive to look is  AllowOverrideList, if both is set to None .htaccess file will be completely ignored.